# Need to Make this Code Sheet Name specific rather then the active sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I got this code on here but need to modify it so it only sees 3 sheets.
  1 is Active Tickets. 
  2 is Closed Tickets.
  3 is Pipeline.
This is the code i currently have:

```
 function onEdit(event)
 {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var actSht = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();

var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
var dateCol = actSht.getLastColumn();
var lastCell = actSht.getRange(index,dateCol);
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

lastCell.setValue(date);
lastCell.setComment("Ultima Modificacion: " + actRng.getA1Notation() +' por     '+Session.getActiveUser());
ss.toast('Ultima Modificacion = '+ actRng.getA1Notation()+' por   '+Session.getActiveUser());
}
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you fix the formatting? As it stands, it is hard to read.

Comment: Sorry about that its been corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpreted your question right you want your script run only if you edit a cell in  one of the three sheets you mentioned.

You can use `getName()` on `actSht` to get the name of the sheet in which you have edited a cell. The you can just use an `IF`-statement to check if it's one of your sheets.

Here's an example of what I described above:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Project" || sheet.getName() == "Tasks"){
    //Some code that only runs if the cell edited is in a sheet named "Projects" or "Tasks"
  }
}
```

And here's how you can apply it to your code:

```
function onEdit(event)
 {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var actSht = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    if(actSht.getName() == "Active Tickets" || actSht.getName() == "Closed Tickets" || actSht.getName() == "Pipeline"){

        var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();

        var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
        var dateCol = actSht.getLastColumn();
        var lastCell = actSht.getRange(index,dateCol);
        var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

        lastCell.setValue(date);
        lastCell.setComment("Ultima Modificacion: " + actRng.getA1Notation() +' por     '+Session.getActiveUser());
        ss.toast('Ultima Modificacion = '+ actRng.getA1Notation()+' por   '+Session.getActiveUser());
    }
}
```